# Style 16px font without calling <p>

Tags: css

Regarding this vertical rhythm setting tool:
http://drewish.com/tools/vertical-rhythm

My p needs a margin-bottom of 1.25em and a margin top of 0em.

My 16px font which lies in the p needs a margin-bottom of 0 and margin-top of 1.25em.

How can i style the 16px without having to call p?

Answer (score 0):

Might it be simpler to just make a p.text class, and call that in the areas where you need to override your general p styles?